# How to add JavaScript object inside another JavaScript object while creating the objects in for loop?

Tags: javascript

I looked other StackOverflow's similar question. But those are pretty much different than what I am looking for.

```
var schemaField = {},
                validation = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < gridConfig.Schemas.length; i++) {
                var schema = gridConfig.Schemas[i];
                schemaField[schema.FieldName] = {
                    type: schema.FieldType,
                    editable: schema.FieldEditable,
                    //Below block is wrong, but this is what I am trying to achieve
                    validation = {
                        required: schema.FieldRequired
                    }                        
                }
            }
```

I need to add that validation object under the main object ***schemaField[schema.FieldName]***. Please help!!!

Comment: `validation: {`

Comment: Why did you do something different for the one thing that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
schemaField[schema.FieldName] = {
    type: schema.FieldType,
    editable: schema.FieldEditable,
    validation: { // note the ":"
        required: schema.FieldRequired
    }
}
```

Objects are merely maps (dictionaries) in JavaScript. You can just continue using the object literal notation: `key: value` where `value` can be anything, including another object literal.

Comment: Thanks Summer. Stupid me

Answer (score 0):

```
var schemaField = {},
validation = {};
for (var i = 0; i < gridConfig.Schemas.length; i++) {
     var schema = gridConfig.Schemas[i];
     schemaField[schema.FieldName] = {
        type: schema.FieldType,
        editable: schema.FieldEditable,
        //Don't assign using = but :
        validation: {
           required: schema.FieldRequired
        } 
     }
     //Or if you want to assign outside
     //schemaField[schema.FieldName].validation = {
     //  required: schema.FieldRequired
     //}                      
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Tremmillicious